# Is there any way to make the text comes below the given headline in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

I want the text to come below the other with complete left in all the devices, Here the text should comes like this,

**Welcome to Services**
User-1 Login

these two must come exactly below to one another.

I have tried textAlign to left and also wrapped them into columns but of no use !! Is there any solution

```
return SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              rAdvisor,
              height: heightOfDevice * 0.3,
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Welcome to Services',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      fontSize: 25,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: rNavyGrey),
                ),
                Text(
                  'User-1 Login',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    color: rNavyGrey,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: yeah u can use Transform.translate to do that

Comment: @JBJason where should i use that !! and for all screens it would work ?

Comment: @KushalHemanthY, your description sounds like you need them in the same line. You need them one below the other and aligned to the left, right?

Comment: { Welcome to Services, User-1 Login }. u wanna make these texts to come from left to Middle as this screen appear ...?   or u wanna make these texts exactly below & horizontally starting from the same point of one another  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need your two text widgets to be **one below the other** and **completely aligned to the left** then use `Column` widget as you have done and set `crossAxisAlignment` to `CrossAxisAlignment.start`.

```dart
return SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              rAdvisor,
              height: heightOfDevice * 0.3,
            ),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Welcome to Services',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      fontSize: 25,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: rNavyGrey),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                Text(
                  'User-1 Login',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    color: rNavyGrey,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I have used that, but it does not work !! Actually i don't want them in single line but i want them to be one beneath another.

Comment: @KushalHemanthy, you need them in the same line, right?

Comment: @KushalHemanthY, one beneath the other, that would mean using a `Column`. What else do you need, so that the answer can be edited correctly.

Comment: Using The CrossAxisAlignment.start worked !! Thanks for that .